# AMD Performance counters: `rdmsr` instruction seems to be blocking

Tags: assembly, linux-kernel, x86, perf, amd-processor

I am currently reading the [AMD Processor Programming Reference Manual](https://developer.amd.com/resources/developer-guides-manuals/) to figure out how to enable and then read performance counters for AMD. It seems to me that in order to enable performance counting, I need to write to register `MSRC001_0200` (Performance Event Select `0`) with the `wrmsr` instruction, while in order to retrieve the counter, I need to read the value with the `rdmsr` instruction from register `MSRC001_0201` (for instance). See Page 172, of the `Preliminary Processor Programming Reference (PPR) for AMD Family 19h Model 21h, Revision B0 Processors (PUB)`. However, when I try to run the following kernel module code, the `rdmsr` instruction seems to be blocking, as the `insmod` command never finishes (without the `rdmsr` command, it does finish though)

```c
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>

void SetUpEvent(void){
    int reg_addr=0xc0010200; 
    int event_no = 0x64;
    int eventMask = 0xC8;
    int event = event_no | (eventMask << 8) | (1 << 16) | (1 << 22);
    __asm__ ("wrmsr" : : "c"(reg_addr), "a"(event), "d"(0x00));
}

/* Read the performance monitor counter */
long int ReadCounter(void){
    long int count;
    long int eax_low, edx_high;
    int reg_addr=0xc0010201; //MSRC001_020[1...B] Performance Event Counter
    __asm__("rdmsr" : "=a"(eax_low), "=d"(edx_high) : "c"(reg_addr));
    count = ((long int)eax_low | (long int)edx_high<<32);
    return count;
}

static int __init lkm_example_init(void) {
 SetUpEvent();
 printk(KERN_INFO "Set up event done \n");
 printk(KERN_INFO "Read counter %ld\n", ReadCounter() );
 return 0;
}
module_init(lkm_example_init);
```

I have no idea how to debug this further or whether my understanding of the AMD manual is incorrect. Any pointers would be great.

**Update:** Through setting up another debug VM I realized that the problem was that while developing the module, I called `insmod` while some other (broken?) version of the code was still running - **hence the hang. The code as posted here seems to be working fine**.

Comment: Does AMD not support `rdpmc` for reading perf counters?

Comment: Any info in syslog? I don't think `rdmsr` can block ... it should either return something or generate an exception.

Comment: What do you see when you single-step this in a VM, e.g. with QEMU + gdb-remote?

Comment: What is this being run on (which CPU model and/or emulator)? Note that @Jester is right (the `rdmsr` can't block) so it's likely it's causing a general protection fault because the MSR doesn't exist; and AMD's manual says MSR C001_0201h is (was?) merely an alias for the correct MSR C001_0004h); so I wonder if changing the code to `int reg_addr=0xc0010204;` would fix it.

Comment: This code is running on an AMD EPYC 7272 12-core processor, which uses the Zen 2 architecture. Changing to `0xc0010204` did not fix the issue unfortunately, it still hangs. I do not see any messages in `journatctl, dmesg, or `/var/log/syslog` - any other places I should look for debugging purposes? @PeterCordes I will set up the debugging to single-step this.

Comment: Through setting up another debug VM I realized that the problem was that while developing the module, I called `insmod` while some other (broken?) version of the code was still running - hence the hang. The code as posted here seems to be working fine now. However, measuring the counter value (which is supposed to be cache misses) twice after some operations does not change the counter, but that is a different problem.